# How can I perform an HTTP request before app bootstrap or init?

Tags: angular

I need to perform an HTTP GET request before my Angular 2 app has been bootstrapped and initialized. How can I do this without having access to the Angular http module?
Maybe exist a way to do the same on initialization of app component with waiting for response?

Answer (score -1):

http is angular module which depends on `HttpModule` so before bootstrap it is not possible to use angular's http either you can use javascript's xmlhttp to get objects from server before app bootstrap